# How to use PHP preg_replace to replace a token

Tags: php, regex

I have a string in $body that looks like this:

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">[COMMENT2]</td>
```

I would like to replace the token [COMMENT2] with the word "None" using something this:

```
$body = preg_replace('\[.*\]', 'None', $body);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You mean like this `[None]` or simply `None` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$body = '<td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">[COMMENT2]</td>';
echo $body = preg_replace('/\[[^]]+\]/', 'None', $body);
//=> <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">None</td>
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY5bX5/1)

#### [PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/V4ssQ)

Comment: That worked for me, thank you.  And thanks for the examples.

Comment: @JohnT Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You should add delimiters `/` or `~` to your regex like this `/\[.*\]/`

**Php code**

```
<?php
   $body='<td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">[COMMENT2]</td>';
   $body = preg_replace('/\[.*?\]/', 'None', $body);
   echo $body;
?>
```

**Output:**

`<td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">None</td>`

<kbd>**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/X4Od3L)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vP1gK6/4)**</kbd>

<kbd>**[More about Php delimiters here.](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)**</kbd>

Comment: and probably use `.*?`, otherwise the `.*` will replace entire swaths of the document if there's 2+ of those tokens

Comment: @MarcB: You are right. Better safe than sorry. I assumed OP had that string in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest another approach (with a `Parser`, that is) ?

```
<?php
$html = '<html>
            <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">[COMMENT2]</td>
        </html>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);

// run an xpath query on the dom
foreach ($xml->xpath("//td[text()='[COMMENT2]']") as &$td)
    $td[0] = 'Some other text';
// just to make sure the html has indeed been changed
echo $xml->asXML();
?>
```

See <kbd>[a working demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/UBzNje)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest with this simple regex:

If you want to replace `[...]`

```
$body = preg_replace('%[^>]+(?=</td>)%i', 'None', $body);
```

If text inside `[` and `]`

```
$body = preg_replace('%(?<=\[)[^>]+(?=\]</td>)%i', 'None', $body);
```

Based on input text

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">[COMMENT2]</td>
```

It will produce

```
<td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid gray;">None</td>
```